# Can we fetch the specific data via using urls in vba

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have 15 different URLs, and I need to fetch price from the particular website in Excel a particular column, can you please help me out. It's my first VBA program and I try but it show my syntax error.

```vb
Sub myfile()    
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer  Dim url As String  Dim item As
    HTMLHtmlElement  Dim Doc As HTMLDocument  Dim tagElements As Object 
    Dim element As Object  Dim lastRow    Application.ScreenUpdating =
    False  Application.DisplayAlerts = False  Application.EnableEvents =
    False  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual    url =
    "https://wtb.app.channeliq.com/buyonline/D_nhoFMJcUal_LOXlInI_g/TOA-60?html=true"

    IE.navigate url    IE.Visible = True    Do  DoEvents  Loop Until
    IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set Doc = IE.document

    lastRow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1    Set tagElements =
    Doc.all.tags("tr")  For Each element In tagElements

      If InStr(element.innerText, "ciq-price")&gt; 0 And
    InStr(element.className, "ciq-product-name") &gt; 0 Then

        Sheet1.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = element.innerText
        ' Exit the for loop once you get the temperature to avoid unnecessary processing
        Exit For   End If  Next

    IE.Quit  Set IE = Nothing    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True  Application.EnableEvents = True 
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Replace the two occurrences of `&gt;` with `>`. Make sure each statement is on a separate line rather than trying to put parts of multiple statements on the same line

Comment: Thank you for your help, I remove those two occurrences but after i ran the code it'll showing me (user-defined type not defined) error

Thank in advance @barrowc

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy any web scraping macro for your purposes. Every page has it's own HTML code structure. So you must write for every page an own web scraping macro.

I can't explain all about web scraping with VBA here. Please start your recherche for information with "excel vba web scraping" and "document object model". Further you need knowlege about HTML and CSS. In best case also about JavaScript:

The error message *user-defined type not defined* ocours because you use early binding without a reference to the libraries *Microsoft HTML Object Library* and *Microsoft Internet Controls*. You can read here how to set a reference via *Tools -> References...* and about the differences between early and late binding [Early Binding v/s Late Binding](http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2018/09/vba-referencing-and-early-binding-vs-late-binding/) and here deeper information from Microsoft [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients)

To get the prices from the shown url you can use the following macro. I use late binding:

```
Option Explicit

Sub myfile()
  Dim IE As Object
  Dim url As String
  Dim tagElements As Object
  Dim element As Object
  Dim item As Object
  Dim lastRow As Long

  lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
  url = "https://wtb.app.channeliq.com/buyonline/D_nhoFMJcUal_LOXlInI_g/TOA-60?html=true"

  Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  IE.navigate url
  IE.Visible = True
  Do: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.readyState = 4

  Set tagElements = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("ciq-online-offer-item  ")

  For Each element In tagElements
    Set item = element.getElementsByTagName("td")(1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = Trim(item.innerText)
    lastRow = lastRow + 1
  Next

  IE.Quit
  Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Edit for a second Example:**
The new link leads to an offer. I assume the price of the product is to be fetched. No loop is needed for this. You just have to find out in which HTML segment the price is and then you can decide how to get it. In the end there are only two lines of VBA that write the price into the Excel spreadsheet.

I'm in Germany and Excel has automatically set the currency sign from Dollar to Euro. This is of course wrong. Depending on where you are, this may have to be intercepted.

```
Sub myfile2()
  Dim IE As Object
  Dim url As String
  Dim tagElements As Object
  Dim lastRow As Long

  lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
  url = "https://www.wayfair.com/kitchen-tabletop/pdx/cuisinart-air-fryer-toaster-oven-cui3490.html"

  Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  IE.navigate url
  IE.Visible = True
  Do: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.readyState = 4
  'Break for 3 seconds
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3))

  Set tagElements = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("BasePriceBlock BasePriceBlock--highlight")(0)
  ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = Trim(tagElements.innerText)

  IE.Quit
  Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @Zwenn, thank for your help and correct me , i'll do the same
Can you please help me one more time , there is another link and I'm not able to get proper tagging what you have did in last code.
"https://www.wayfair.com/kitchen-tabletop/pdx/cuisinart-air-fryer-toaster-oven-cui3490.html?domain=channeliq.com&cjevent=2cd5632148dd11ea83b6005e0a180514&refID=CJ314743-CJ2617611&PID=CJ7819916&clickid=2cd5632148dd11ea83b6005e0a180514"

Comment: @RAHULKUMAROJHA I have added the example as an edit in my answer.

Comment: I'm from india and i also try the same but its show object and block error

Comment: I also include tue library html and internet controls. And one more thing is this possible to use multiple urls for same purpose@Zwenn

Comment: @RAHULKUMAROJHA I have inserted a pause of 3 seconds in example 2. This is necessary if a page is still loading data although the browser says that loading is finished. In these cases, you get a runtime error because the objects below cannot yet be formed.

Comment: You only need the references to the libraries if you use Early Binding. You can fetch prices from multiple URLs with the same macro if the pages have the same structure. In example 2 a price is read from an offer. With a loop around the code, in which the URL is also adjusted each time, you can get as many prices as you like from offers on the domain. But I think you should first learn something about structured programming. Core statement: Every problem can be solved with the three control structures *sequence*, *selection* and *iteration*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming